# Spread number equally across elements of array (and add remainder to beginning of ring)

Tags: json, jq

Let's say I have some JSON array, we'll call it `A`:

`["foo", "bar", "baz"]`

And I have some number `X`, let's say 5 in this case.

I want to produce the following object in jq:

```
{
  "foo": 2,
  "bar": 2,
  "baz": 1,
}
```

This is the number 5 divided up equally across the elements of the array, with the remainder being distributed to the elements at the beginning of the ring. You could maybe think of it this way, the value for element `N` should be `ceil(X / length(A))` if `index(N) < (X % length(A))`, otherwise it should be `floor(X / length(A))`.

Assuming `A` is my file input to jq, and I have `X` defined as a variable, how can I express this in jq?

I have tried `'length as $len | .[] | if index(.) < (5 % $len) then (5 / $len) + 1 else 5 / $len end' | 5` as a starting point but I get 2 for each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `transpose` function to help build this. It's simpler with a `ceil` function, which we have to define ourselves. The mapping you are looking for from index to allocation is `ceil($count - $i)/$n)`, where `$count` is the amount you are distributing, `$i` is the index in the original list, and `$n` is the length of the list.

Comments show how each piece works on your sample input of `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`.

```
def ceil(v): -(-v | floor);
def objectify(n): {key: .[0], value: ceil(($count - .[1])/n)}; 
  # ["foo", 0] | objectify(3) -> {"key": "foo", "value", 2}
length as $n |   # n == 3
[., keys]    |   # [["foo", "bar", "baz"], [0,1,2]]
[transpose[] |   # [["foo", 0], ["bar", 1], ["baz", 2]]
    objectify($n)
] |
from_entries # {"foo": 2, "bar": 2, "baz": 1}
```

Without the comments...

```
def ceil(v): -(-v | floor);
def objectify(n): {key: .[0], value: ceil(($count - .[1])/n)};
length as $n | [., keys] | [transpose[] | objectify($n)] | from_entries
```

An example of its use, assuming you saved it to file named `distribute.jq`:

```
jq --argjson count 5 -f distribute.jq tmp.json
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually was able to get this to work but instead of using from_entries I used add (in a similar vein as my own answer)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `ceil` was added as a jq builtin long ago, but after the release of jq 1.5. That is, it is not yet part of the most recent “official” release.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution by saving the original input as a variable so that I can continue to reference it while operating on its values.

```
. as $arr
| length as $len
| [
    .[]
    | . as $i
    | {
        $(i): (
          if ($arr | index($i)) < ($x % $len) then
            ($x / $len) + 1
          else
            $x / $len
          end
          | floor
        )
      }
  ]
| add
```

The following worked for me with passing `--argjson count $X` and feeding the array as my input.

Comment: Use `--argjson` to avoid the need to call `tonumber`, assuming `$X` is a simple number.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I edited this answer to account for that.